# write a efficient for loop in bash for multiple files (.PDB files)

Tags: bash, grep, sed, awk

I have problem with this script:

```bash
#!/bin/bash
for filename in /home/hb/pg/ensemble/pdbs/P24941/raw_pdb/*.pdb; do
    grep COMPND $filename | grep "CHAIN:" -B 1 | sed 's/COMPND//g' | sed 's/CHAIN\://g' | sed 's+[0-9]++g' | sed 's/--//g' | sed 's\MOLECULE:\\g' | sed 's/;/,/g' | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/' | awk 'NF' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /' > trimmed.csv
mv trimmed.csv /home/hb/pg/ensemble/pdbs/P24941/raw_pdb/trimmed
done
```

I have ~800 pdb files like this:

```
> ls -lXGHh --group-directories-first  
total 234M
drwxr-xr-x 1 xx  18K Jun  9 18:13 overall_chains
drwxr-xr-x 1 xx   22 Jun  9 22:13 trimmed
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx    9 May 15 09:43 README.md
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx 224K May  9 10:20 1AQ1.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx 244K May  9 10:21 1B38.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx 238K May  9 10:21 1B39.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx 272K Jun  9 07:19 1BUH.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx 224K May  9 10:21 1CKP.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx 222K May  9 10:21 1DI8.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx 222K May  9 10:21 1DM2.pdb
-rw-r--r-- 1 xx 239K May  9 10:21 1E1V.pdb
...
```

This is one example file with its first 20 lines:

```
HEADER    CELL CYCLE                              16-OCT-00   1E9H              
TITLE     THR 160 PHOSPHORYLATED CDK2 - HUMAN CYCLIN A3 COMPLEX WITH            
TITLE    2 THE INHIBITOR INDIRUBIN-5-SULPHONATE BOUND                           
COMPND    MOL_ID: 1;                                                            
COMPND   2 MOLECULE: CELL DIVISION PROTEIN KINASE 2;                            
COMPND   3 CHAIN: A, C;                                                         
COMPND   4 SYNONYM: CYCLIN-DEPENDENT KINASE 2, CDK2;                            
COMPND   5 EC: 2.7.1.37;                                                        
COMPND   6 ENGINEERED: YES;                                                     
COMPND   7 OTHER_DETAILS: PHOSPHORYLATED ON THR 160 CHAINS A AND C              
COMPND   8  ARE ASYMETRIC UNIT COPIES;                                          
COMPND   9 MOL_ID: 2;                                                           
COMPND  10 MOLECULE: CYCLIN A3;                                                 
COMPND  11 CHAIN: B, D;                                                         
COMPND  12 SYNONYM: A3;                                                         
COMPND  13 ENGINEERED: YES;                                                     
COMPND  14 OTHER_DETAILS: TRUNCATED FRAGMENT OF CYCLIN A. IN COMPLEX            
COMPND  15  WITH CDK2 CHAINS B AND D ARE ASYMETRIC UNIT COPIES                  
SOURCE    MOL_ID: 1;                                                            
SOURCE   2 ORGANISM_SCIENTIFIC: HOMO SAPIENS;
```

I want to run simple script to read **every ".PDB" file** and **collect** and update a **single csv file** with its output.

I can achieve the output for a single file:

```bash
grep COMPND 1E9H.pdb | grep "CHAIN:" -B 1 | sed 's/COMPND//g' | sed 's/CHAIN\://g' | sed 's+[0-9]++g' | sed 's/--//g' | sed 's\MOLECULE:\\g' | sed 's/;/,/g' | sed 'N;s/\(.*\)\n\(.*\)/\2\n\1/' | awk 'NF' | sed 'N;s/\n/ /'
```

The output for this single file is:

```
A, C,             CELL DIVISION PROTEIN KINASE ,                            
CYCLIN A, B, D,
```

I want to trim all pdb files in a directory and then move them to a specific directory (trimmed directory). Any solution?

Thanks all for your answers.

I tried write the bash script but I've got just a single row csv file.

Comment: Do your want to "*update a single csv file*" or "*want to trim all pdb files in a directory and then move them to a specific directory*".

Comment: @Cyrus I want to trim pdbs with _grep_ and _sed_ and _awk_ then put all outputs of all pdb files in a single csv file.

Comment: I'd recommend checking out the "Bash guides" at www.tldp.org - they're slightly old but still good for getting up to speed with bash.

Answer (score 1):

(First, a question: Why have the `mv` command instead of writing to the desired path directly?)

There are two basic ways you could go about this: You can *append* to the output file instead of overwriting it, using `>>` instead of `>`:

```sh
for i in *.pdb; do
  echo processing "$i" >> for-loop-output.txt
done
```

You can also put the output redirection elsewhere:

```sh
for i in *.pdb; do
  echo processing "$i"
done > for-loop-output.txt
```

The latter is probably more efficient, because the output file is only opened once. However, for just 800 files, that doesn’t matter all that much.